# Trace binary execution to reduce size

Tags: linux, unix, trace

When a program is run, only certain parts of the code are actually executed. Especially when using more complex frameworks a lot of boilerplate is included with the code that never gets actually executed.

**Question:** Is it possible to trace the execution of a program with the purpose of dumping only the used instructions to disk and in this way obtain a much leaner and smaller binary?

EDIT: I understand that the leaner binary won't be 100% equivalent to the original program, especially in corner cases. I just would like to have a leaner version that works under a stable regime.

Comment: Are you saying that the linker is doing an inadequate job of this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, My question goes even beyond compiled languages, for example what if a Python program is running in a stable regime and we could trace and somehow dump to disk only the actual code paths being executed? In this way we could have a smaller binary and avoid the rest of the standard library needing to be packaged.

Comment: Capturing all possible error paths would be problematic.

Comment: @keithmo, yes. I don't expect the extracted program to be 100% equivalent in functionality to the original program. I want to get the smallest program under a stable regime.